# How to make a commandblock 1 time use for a player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if there was a way I could make a commandblock with a command that will only give someone an item once. For example, Someone presses a button and gets an item, they cannot use that command block again, but someone else could come and use it, and than they cannot use it again.

Answer (score 3):

You could tag a player with a chain command block after the first command block

Use this command to tag the nearest player within a distance of 5 blocks who doesn't already have a `gotIt` tag with `gotIt`.

```
/tag @p[distance=..5,tag=!gotIt] add gotIt
```

Use that tag with the /give command.

This command would give the item to the nearest player within a distance of 5 who does not have the `gotIt` tag:

```
/give @p[distance=..5,tag=!gotIt] <item>
```

Make sure that both commands execute at the same coordinates, you would have to use `/execute` with at least one of them.

```
/execute positioned <coordinates> give @p[distance=..5,tag=!gotIt] <item>
/execute positioned <coordinates> tag @p[distance=..5,tag=!gotIt] add gotIt
```

Make sure that you`/give` the item before you `/tag` that player